# Window Position of a CHM file

Tags: chm, html-help-workshop

I just compiled and viewed a CHM file used in my project. I noticed that the viewer remembers the window size and position across sessions.

Where does the HTML help viewer save the window position for each CHM file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These settings are stored in a file called HH.DAT. On Windows XP, this file can be found in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\HTML Help\hh.dat
```

Other OS versions put it in different places. There is one such file per user profile. On Windows 10 this file can be found in:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\HTML Help\hh.dat
```

Looking at the contents of the file, there seems to be a header, a list of help file names, some blank space to accommodate more file names, then some binary values that would most likely be the window size and position. If you're comfortable working with binary file formats, then with some experimentation it should be possible to work out the structure and extract the values for a given CHM file.

Here are some websites that talk about this file:

- [Adobe Support Community - formerly RoboHelp](https://community.adobe.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&filter=location&location=forum-board:robohelp&q=hh.dat)

  talks about hh.dat
- [HTML Help Tech Info](http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/hh_info)

  lots of history about help file formats, also many utilities to work with CHM files
- [Help-Info.de - Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.help-info.de/en/xml/maml_faq.xml#HTMLHelp)

  info about many help file formats, and examples of how to make use of them from code

Comment: You're welcome. But I guess the technology of CHM help files is running out. Bad news - Microsoft dropped the download for the HTML Help Workshop and therefore also for the compiler last month. Among other things, I think it prepares for the final elimination of Internet Explorer, which is still present in the background in Windows 10. Who still has the `htmlhelp.exe` SetUp should take good care of it or use the Internet Archives. I am now a retired developer ...